# Hypercover and hyper descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, algebraic-stacks

I am trying to understand the descent condition using hypercovers. The condition says that a hyper cover of a scheme $X$ is a simplicial set $Y_{\bullet}$ that satisfies the condition $Y_n\rightarrow Cosk_{n-1}(Y_{\bullet})_n$ is surjective etale map. I am just trying to understand the condition $Y_2\rightarrow Cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2$. Can anyone explain how to think about the condition? How does it generalise the concept of triple intersection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully a topological analogy is close enough... (and I might have gotten some pieces wrong so hopefully others can help)

If $X$ is a space and $Z_{\bullet} = N \mathcal{U}_{\bullet}$ is the Čech nerve of an open cover $\{U_i\}$ then lets go through as a warmup why $Z_n \to Cosk_{n-1} (Z_{\bullet})_n$ is a covering.

For $n=0$ we want $Z_0 = \coprod U_i \to Cosk_{-1} (Z_{\bullet})_0$ to be a covering. But $0$-simplices of $Cosk_{-1} (Z_{\bullet})$ are $0$ simplices of the constant (augmented) simplicial set induced by $X$ and so we are asking $\coprod U_i \to X$ to be a covering map. Great.

For $n=1$ we want $Z_1 = \coprod U_{ij} \to Cosk_{0} (Z_{\bullet})_1$ to be a covering. But $1$-simplices of $Cosk_{0} (Z_{\bullet})$ are $1$ simplices of the (augmented) simplicial set induced by $Z_0 = \coprod U_i \to X$. These satisfy some matching condition by the coskeleton which basically result in points which are in the intersections of some $U_i$ and some $U_j$, i.e. $\coprod U_{ij}$ and so we are asking $Z_1 = \coprod U_{ij} \to \coprod U_{ij}$ to be a covering map and it's actually an isomorphism. Great.

I think for all $n \ge 1$ it is in fact an isomorphism because the matching condition is so strong for the Čech nerve when analyzing the coskeleton.

Now let's assume $Y_{\bullet}$ is a hypercovering.

For $n=0$ we see as above that $Y_0 = \coprod U_i$. But now for $n=1$ we only need that $Y_1 \to \coprod U_{ij}$ is a covering. This means that we can think of $Y_1 = \coprod_{ij} \coprod_{\alpha \in I_{ij}} U_{ij,\alpha}\simeq \{ (x,ij, \alpha) \vert x \in U_{ij;\alpha} \subset U_{ij}\}$ is like a covering of the double intersections of the $U_{ij}$.

For $n=2$ when we analyze the matching condition for a point which is in $U_{ij, \alpha}$, $U_{kl, \beta}$, and $U_{mn, \gamma}$ you can unpack this to show that it in fact can be indexed as:

$$Z_2 = \coprod_{ijk} \coprod_{ \substack{\alpha \in I_{ij},\\ \beta \in I_{jk},\\ \gamma \in I_{ik} }} \coprod_{ p \in I_{ijk, \alpha \beta \gamma}} U_{ijk, \alpha \beta \gamma, p}$$

If it's the unpacking of the matching condition I can try to say more another time. If it's that my analogy is too topological, then my apologies!

**Addition/Edit: $cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2$**

To be slightly more precise from the above, let's analyze some of these sets. $X$ is a space and $Z_0 = \coprod U_i \simeq \{(x ,i)\in X \times I \vert i \in I \text{ and } x \in U_i \}$. Similarly, $Z_1 = \coprod U_{ij} \simeq \{ (x, ij) \vert x \in U_i \cap U_j\}$. The two face maps $Z_1 \to Z_0$ then are $d_1(x,ij) \mapsto (x,i)$ and ${d_0}:(x,ij) \mapsto (x,j)$. Similarly we have $Y_0 =  \coprod U_i \simeq \{(x ,i) \in X \vert i \in I \text{ and } x \in U_i \}$ and $Y_1 = \coprod_{ij} \coprod_{\alpha \in I_{ij}} U_{ij,\alpha}\simeq \{ (x,ij, \alpha) \vert x \in U_{ij;\alpha} \subset U_{ij}\}$ but now $d_1(x,ij;\alpha) \mapsto (x,i)$ and ${d_0}:(x,ij; \alpha) \mapsto (x,j)$.

Now as you said an element in $cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2$ is a "hollow triangle". So we have a 2-simplex consisting of three edges whose vertices match: $(x, ij, \alpha \in I_{ij}), (x, jk, \beta \in I_{jk}), (x, ik, \gamma \in I_{jk})$ so that $d_0(x, ij, \alpha \in I_{ij}) = (x,j) = d_1(x, jk, \beta \in I_{jk})$, etc. This is a point $x \in X$ which by looking above is in the triple intersection $U_{ij, \alpha} \cap U_{jk, \beta} \cap U_{ik, \gamma}  \subset U_{ijk}$.

So asking for a covering map $Y_2 \to cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2$ is asking for coverings of all such triple intersections $U_{ij, \alpha} \cap U_{jk, \beta} \cap U_{ik, \gamma}  \subset U_{ijk}$.

Finally, again, in the case of $Z_2$ we have an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But I did not understand how to think about the condition $Y_2\rightarrow cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_{2}$. I completely understand $Y_1\rightarrow cosk_0(Y_{\bullet})_{1}$

Comment: I see. So would unpacking that second condition help more or my answer was helpful as it is?

Comment: thanks for asking. yes, that was precisely my question. I tried doing it but something was wrong. So $cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2=Hom(sk_1(\Delta[2]), Y_{\bullet})$ and $sk_1(\Delta[2])$ is just a hollow triangle. and the condition is saying that we can always fill up a hollow triangle. But I do not understand how to arrive at the topological things that you wrote using the simplicial data. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you're welcome. I was very happy the first time all of this made sense to me so I'm happy to share when I feel like I actually understand something on this site hah. I added "Addition/Edit: $cosk_1(Y_{\bullet})_2$" at the bottom which should address your question. I think the key is how to actually write elements of the coproduct and the face maps as I tried to unpack.